# Change the size of Google Photos after it been uploaded

Tags: google-photos

I've been uploaded photos to Google Photos with `original size` instead of `high quality`.
Now, my Google storage (Drive) is full and I want to change the size of the already uploaded photos to the `high quality` option for unlimited photos backup.

How can I change the size of the photos after it already been uploaded?

Here is a screenshot with an explanation from Google:
[image]

[Source of screenshot](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from the Google Photos web app settings page.

1. Go to http://photos.google.com from your browser.
2. Click on the settings button ([image]).
3. Click the `Recover Storage` button.

[image]

That it :)